# How Do I Define a Custom Directory to Store a User Configuration? [C#]

Tags: c#, application-settings

I made [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642967/how-can-i-change-the-save-directory-of-properties-settings-default?noredirect=1#comment68519810_40642967) question on here a bit ago, but I have honestly no idea how to go about this. I was told to have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171565(v=vs.110).aspx) link regarding my problem, but MSDN did not help me in the slighest and I cannot figure out how to store my default settings in somewhere other than AppData.

Basically, I'm making a security program that will monitor and report to an administrator when something blacklisted is run, but if the administrator's configuration saves to AppData, only one user account will be secure! This will mean that the administrator would have to setup the program on every single user account which is obviously impractical.

Instead, I'd like to have it so it saves in the "Program Files" directory. This will make it so the particular user could not alter the configuration as they would not have permissions to do so.

Could someone please help me out with this?

Thanks,

MTS11648

Answer (score 0):

To get the path to program files using the special folders

```
 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
```

Which will return a string containing their full path,
Then you can create you custom Directory inside those using

```
Directory.CreateDirectory();
```

Comment: I know how to get the path to the program files folder, but what I'm looking for is to save an app configuration file (similar to that of Properties.Settings.Default) that will be stored in the program files folder. So this way, settings will be the same across all user accounts.

Comment: why don't you store that in a binary file for example?